# Custom Header in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, header

I am created the Custom header and it is working fine. But include child links also showing. I don't want to show child links. Only my custom code will appear How to do.

**Block/Header.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\TopHeader\Block;

class Header extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header{


    protected $_template = 'Learning_TopHeader::custom_header.phtml';


}
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" type="Learning\TopHeader\Block\Header" />
</config>
```

**view/frontend/templates/custom_header.xml**

## Custom Header

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following code on your default.xml of your theme/module and change accordingly:

```
  <referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->

</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
```

in *app/design///Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*